# select second lowest 'id' value of a variable

Tags: mysql

how can I edit this code so that it selects the $name with the second lowest 'id' value:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='$name' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
```

I thought it might be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='$name' ORDER BY id ASC + 1 LIMIT 1
```

but that wasn't right. Any Ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify an offset like so:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='$name' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
```

or like so:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='$name' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1, 1
```

In the latter case, the first number is the offset, and the second is the number of elemenets returned.

#### See also:

- [SELECT Syntax - MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Answer (score 2):

try

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM users 
   WHERE name = '$name' 
ORDER BY id ASC 
   LIMIT 1, 1
```

Doc:

> Definition: **Limit** is used to limit your MySQL query results to those
>   that fall within a specified range. You can use it to show the first X
>   number of results, or to show a range from X - Y results. It is
>   phrased as Limit X, Y and included at the end of your query. X is the
>   starting point (remember the first record is 0) and Y is the duration
>   (how many records to display).

Example :

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 0, 10
```

This will display the first 10 results from the database.

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 5, 5
```

This will show records 6, 7, 8, 9, and 10

Comment: so if you wanted to select the third would it be LIMIT 1,2 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the offset in your limit clause:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='$name' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1, 1
```

Comment: so if you wanted to select the third would it be LIMIT 1,2 ?

Comment: first the offset and then the record count: `limit 2, 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='$name' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1,1;
```

Comment: so if you wanted to select the third would it be LIMIT 1,2 ?